# Excel VBA code for textbox value dependent on dropdown list value using named ranges

Tags: vba, excel

## What I have:

1. I have a custom user form in Excel VBA.
2. The form contains a dropdown list (***industry category***) and textbox (corresponding ***industry specifier***).
3. For each ***industry category*** there is one ***industry specifier*** (an acronym version of the category).
4. The ***industry category*** and ***industry specifier*** will always be of the same row.
5. The dropdown list is populated from a name range of cells.

## What I need:

The value of the textbox needs to be dependent on the value of the dropdown-list.

e.g. When an ***industry category*** is selected, the corresponding ***industry code*** should appear in the textbox.

## My cell structure:

Column A (***Industry Category***):

```
Agriculture                               
Art and photography                       
Arts and theatre                          
Charity and non-profit                    
Corporate                                   
Educational and academic
```

Column B (***Industry Specifier***):

```
ag
ap
at
cn
co
ea
```

## My VBA code:

Populating the dropdown list for ***industry category***:

```
'Populate Industry combo box.
Dim range_c As Range
Dim ws_c As Worksheet
Set ws_c = Worksheets("4.1 List data")

For Each range_c In ws_c.Range("IndustryList")
  With Me.Industry
    .AddItem range_c.Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = range_c.Offset(0, 1).Value
  End With
Next range_c
```

Textbox for ***industry specifier***:

```
IndustrySpecifier.Value = ""
```

## What I've tried:

I've reviewed tutorials on how to achieve what I need using VBA code alone but I don't know where to begin using dependent named ranges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim range_c As Range

    For Each range_c In Worksheets("4.1 List data").Range("IndustryList")
      With Me.Industry
        .AddItem range_c.Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = range_c.Offset(0, 1).Value
      End With
    Next range_c
End Sub

Private Sub Industry_Change()
    With Me.Industry
        If .ListIndex = -1 Then
            IndustrySpecifier.Text = ""
        Else
            IndustrySpecifier.Text = .List(.ListIndex, 1)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]